# Need help refining my RegEx for C# style double slash comments

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create RegEx to match C# comments (the double slash kind). The RegEx I have created almost works perfectly, except if there is a line that has just two backslashes and no actual comment, it starts matching the next line, which it shouldn't do. Here is my regex:

```
(?![\n\r])\s?//[\w\W].+
```

Here is my test data:

```
using System;

// This is a comment

public class test
{
    // this is also a comment
    // Hello!
    //
}
```

My RegEx matches everything as expected except the line that has just the `//`. The RegEx I have matches the `//` and the final brace, which isn't right.

Comment: As a side note, those are forward slashes. :-)

Comment: A question: do you need to also match comments like `var c //this `?

Comment: @DanPuzey -- You are correct. I just updated my question correcting that.

Comment: Gabber: Yes, but it is already doing that fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
(?![\n\r])\s?//.*?$
```

will match to the end of the line and no more.

Comment: Nope. This RegEx seems to match JUST the lone double slashes and none of the other ones lol

Comment: edited, sorry. Btw I don't understand the [\w\W], would you explain please? I left this part out of my regex

Comment: Also because if you try to match `[\w\W]` and you have just `//` followed by a newline char, this `//` won't be matched

Comment: I was putting in the [\w\W] because I was under the impression that would match any word, essentially matching everything after the //

Comment: Also, I tested your RegEx and its not matching anything at all now.

Comment: If I remove the trailing "?$" from your RegEx Gabber, it seems to work though! Let me test more thoroughly

Comment: $ means "until the end of line" this should be there ... However if your regex settings don't make the dot match newlines then it's ok to remove $!!!!!!!

Comment: That's weird. I'm using [RegEx Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) to test it and it doesn't match.

Comment: Gabber - figured it out. I have to turn MultiLine on in RegEx Hero, then your RegEx matches perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
(?![\n\r])\s?//\w?
```

Should catch just the comments in your sample.